# "Chain Rule" for Finite Difference Operator

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, recurrence-relations, factorial

I am trying to prove using difference calculus the following formula;

$$\Delta(a+bx)^{(n)}=bn(a+bx)^{(n-1)}$$
which is akin to the chain rule for continuous Calculus.  Here we have that

$$x^{(n)}=x(x-1)...(x-n+1)$$

and

$$\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$$

It seemed daunting at first so I tried small values; $a=3, b=2$.  Looking at the relationship with actual values would help generate an idea how the general proof would look.  So I started;

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\Delta(3+2x)^{(n)}&=&[3+2(x+1)]^{(n)}-(3+2x)^{(n)}\\&=&(5+2x)^{(n)}-(3+2x)^{(n)}\\&=&(2x+5)(2x+4)(2x+3)^{(n-2)}-(2x+3)^{(n-2)}(2x+5-n)(2x+4-n)\\&=&(2x+3)^{(n-2)}[(2x+5)(2x+4)-(2x+5-n)(2x+4-n)]\\&=&(2x+3)^{(n-2)}[n(2x+5)+n(2x+4)-n^2]\\&=&n(2x+3)^{(n-2)}[(2x+5)+(2x+4)-n]\\&=&n(2x+3)^{(n-2)}(4x+9-n)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

This last couple of steps is escaping me.  I can't really factor a 2 without ending up with a $1/2$n.  I know that if I can manipulate the last term into something close to $2(2x+3-(n-2))$ then this should give me what I need, but this expanded is $$(4x+6-2n+4)=4x+10-2n=4x+9-n+(1-n)$$ and so I'm missing a $(1-n)$.

DId I screw up some algebra?

EDIT;  @ancientmathematician, you were right, and my definition of $p(x)^{(n)}$ was incorrect, and is defined as

$$p(x)^{(n)}=p(x)p(x-1)...p(x-n+1)$$

which I'm sure will change things around.  I will go through the algebra shortly and If I solve it i will answer my own question, or someone else can write it up and I'll upvote it.

Comment: What does the $^{(n)}$ mean?

Comment: $$x^{(n)}=x(x-1)...(x-n+1)$$  Its also known as the falling factorial, and there are a few different notations I've seen.

Comment: I( think you have to say what $p(x)^{(n)}$ means.

Comment: Ok so there is just one thing I don't get. You try to get the RHS to be something $^{(n-1)}$, and instead of $n-1$ you make a $n-2$ appear artificially. Why?

Comment: Well, I noticed that they had $n-2$ factors that were equal, so I figured to start with what I had and try to manipulate the last term so that I could adjust it afterward and multiply by that last factor and change to $(n-1)$

Comment: I see. But this number of equal terms is not always going to be so close to $n-1$, it is here only because you chose $2$ and $3$.

Comment: I see what your saying.  I just noticed I was so close, and so I'm thinking I made an algebra mistake above...  and @ancientmathematician, I think that $$p(x)^{(n)}=p(x)[p(x)-1]...[p(x)-(n-1)]$$

Comment: I think this is effectively Proposition 1(1) of section 2 of this: https://ijpam.eu/contents/2014-96-2/3/3.pdf. But it would be nice just to sort out the algebra here.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, see my edit above, $p(x)^{(n)}$ is defined differently than above and is defined in my edit above.

Comment: So the book I'm working out of states that the statement $f(x)^{(n)}$ is DEFINED to be $$f(x)^{(n)}=f(x)f(x-1)f(x-2)...f(x-n+1)$$ So i guess this is defined this way for a reason. I haven't had time to go through the algebra, but given this change, I thnk it must work out...

Comment: @littleO intuitively, i thought my original definition and your statement above  made the most sense in terms of the "factorial" as a product of successively decreasing terms, but we were wrong...

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Thanks. What book are you reading, by the way?

Comment: I picked it up at the library to help supplement Bernoulli polynomial research , and it's a nice introduction to difference equations.  It's called "An Introduction to the Calculus of Finite Differences and Difference Equations" by Kenneth S. Miller.   It's old, published in 60, but its a good intro.

Comment: Thanks, @Eleven-Eleven, I thought that was how it used to be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the algebra works out when using the definition you gave in the edit.

Let $h(x) = f(x)^{(n)} = f(x)f(x-1)\cdots f(x-n+1)$. Then
\begin{align}
\Delta h(x) &= f(x+1) f(x) f(x-1) \cdots f(x-n+2) - f(x)f(x-1)\cdots f(x-n+1) \\
&= f(x) f(x-1) \cdots f(x-n+2)(f(x+1) - f(x-n+1)) \\
&= (f(x+1) - f(x-n+1)) f(x)^{(n-1)}.
\end{align}
In the special case that $f(x) = a + bx$, we have
\begin{align}
f(x+1) - f(x-n+1) &= a + bx + b - (a + bx - (n-1) b) \\
&= nb.
\end{align}
So we find that
$$
\Delta h(x) = nb (a + bx)^{(n-1)}.
$$

Comment: Once I saw the real definition of $f(x)^{(n)}$ i knew this would work out.  Thanks for the proof.